# If $\Sigma \vdash \phi$ implies $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$ then $\Sigma \vdash \phi \to \varphi$ on propositional logic?

Tags: logic

My main aim is to prove or disprove that if $\Sigma \vdash \phi$ implies $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$ then $\Sigma \vdash \phi \to \varphi$ where $\Sigma$ donotes a set of sentences in propositional logic.

$\Sigma \vdash \phi$ means there is a deduction from $\Sigma$ where the deduction is a sequence $( \alpha_0 , \dots , \alpha_n)$ with $a_i$ is either in $\Sigma$ or a consequence of MP (that is, for some $j,k<i$ $\alpha_k = \alpha_j \to \alpha_i$ and $\alpha_i$ follows from them) or a tautology.

I'm completely stuck now. I tried to prove it but have no idea on how to bring $\phi$ to a deduction sequence. And I also tried to make a counterexmaple but no simple one I could find.

Even in my mere intuition, I cannot clearly judge whether it is true or false.

(I also thought of employing Completeness and Soundness Thm..)

Comment: Have we some informations about the set of *axioms* and *rules* ? i.e.is the *classical* (Hilbert-style) system for *propositional logic* (like Mendelson's one) ? If we do not have these kind of information, I thin we are not licensed to use in the argument the concepts of *tautology* or *completeness*; we may only use the "general" properties of the *derivation* relation ($\vdash$).

Comment: it all depents on what is in $ \Sigma $ if s is just $ { P, Q} $ (two independent propositions) then you cannot really proof $ P \to Q $ because there is just nothing else to prove. but probably  $ \Sigma $ contains also some axioms of axiomschemes, and then it depends on what the axiomschemes are

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But what if weakening ( $ \varphi \to (\phi \to \varphi ) $ ) is not an element of $ \Sigma $ ? (we have no reason to assume it is) but it looks the OP has abadomed this question so i guess we will never know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take Σ here to be just the axioms of propositional logic, and take $\phi$ to be some propositional atom $p$.  Then Σ ⊢ $\phi$ is false, and thus "Σ ⊢ $\phi$ implies Σ ⊢ $\varphi$" is true for any $\varphi$. Now take $\varphi$ to be some other atom $q$.  $[p \rightarrow q]$ is not a tautology.  If a formula is not a tautology, then it is not provable from Σ, because of the soundness metatheorem.  So, Σ ⊢ $(\phi \rightarrow \varphi)$ is false.  Thus, "if Σ ⊢ ϕ implies Σ ⊢ φ then Σ ⊢ $(\phi \rightarrow \varphi)$" is false in general.

(In fact $p,q$ need not be atoms; they can be taken to be any independent formulas.  That is, formulas such that for each pair of truth values $(b_1,b_2)$, there is at least one valuation for which $p$ and $q$ take values $b_1$ and $b_2$ respectively.)

Comment: This is incorrect.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: What is wrong with it (except for the implicit assumption that $\Sigma$ proves neither statement)?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I read the problem incorrectly. Anyway, Doug, for clarity, you may want to indicate what your $\Sigma$ is (it could be empty, but something needs to be said).

Comment: If Σ ⊢ c, where c is any contingent proposition, then the soundness theorem fails.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Σ almost surely can't be empty for this problem, because the only presumed rule is modus ponendo ponens "Here Σ⊢ϕ means there is a deduction from Σ where the deduction is a sequence (α0,…,αn) with ai is either in Σ or implication αj→αk or a consequence of MP," and it seems likely that we're talking about classical logic here.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Yes, you are right. I suspect that's a typo and the OP forgot to include that each $\alpha_i$ could also be an instance of a propositional axiom. Thanks for clarifying, though.

Comment: Sorry about that. $\alpha_i$ can definitely be a tautology.

Comment: A question. For your solution to work I guess $\Sigma$ should be empty?

Comment: @julypraise No, Σ doesn't have to not have any members.  Suppose Σ to be {CCpqCCqrCpr, CCNppp, CpCNpq} (which is an axiom set for C-N... conditional-negation classical logic in Polish notation... the argument will work for any axiom set for classical logic).  This argument will still work.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not sure I follow you.  I was thinking about the lines of using ϕ→(ψ→ϕ) at first also, but we want Σ⊢ϕ→φ to fail here.  So, we do NOT want φ as a tautology.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: I have heavily edited your answer — I hope you don’t mind.  Partly for a minor correction (it isn’t enough just for $p$ and $q$ to each be contingent, they also need to be independent of each other) but mainly for style, since from comments it looks like I wasn’t the only one who found your original answer a bit unclear to read.  The essential content of the counterexample is unchanged, though.